# Update view by date in real-time / SwiftUI

Tags: swift, date, swiftui, mvvm, view

I was wondering if you could help me with a SwiftUI question. Specifically, I'm trying to update my ForEach loop in my view at midnight or when the date changes. All dates in my model are in "dd.MM.yyyy" format and fetching by date to ForEach loop. How can I reload ForEach loop with new events in real-time changing the date or at midnight?
Any tips or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

---

**VM**

---

```
import Foundation

@MainActor
final class TodaysEventsViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var events = [EventModel]()
    @Published var event = [Event]()
    
    @Published var selectedEvent: Event?
    
    @Published var date = Date()
    
    private var stringDate: String {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy"
        let currentDateString = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
        return currentDateString
    }
    
    init() {
        fetchEvents()
        getTodaysEvents()
    }
    
    private func fetchEvents() {
        let eventsData = Bundle.main.decode([EventModel].self, from: "EventsData.json")
        events = eventsData
    }
    
    private func getTodaysEvents() {
        if let index = events.first(where: {$0.date == stringDate}) {

        event = index.event

        }
    }
}
```

---

**View**

---

```
import SwiftUI

struct TodaysEventsView: View {
    
    @StateObject private var viewModel = TodaysEventsViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack(spacing: 7.5) {
            ForEach(viewModel.event, id: \.id) { event in
                Button {
                    self.viewModel.selectedEvent = event
                } label: {
                    EventCell(event: event)
                }
            }
        }
        .sheet(item: $viewModel.selectedevent) { event in
            EventDetailView(event: event)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at local notifications or timers, you could set one up when the app starts that fires at midnight.

Comment: Show a minimal reproducible code that produces your issue, see: [minimal code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Currently, you have in `TodaysEventsView` a `ForEach(viewModel.event, id: \.id)` 
but `viewModel.event` is empty. Also you do not declare `holiday`. The code cannot compile, and 
the only date you show is in `holiday`, not in the loop and no code for the Event.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Thanks a lot, I'll look into the timers and notifications. But is there a way to update the view in real time? For example, in the simulator when I change the date on macOS and do not reload the app in the simulator?

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine Sorry, fixed it...

Comment: You could have a timer that repeatedly fires every minute for instance and checks if the current data has changed if you want to but it feels a bit overkill. Note that this isn’t about SwiftUI and you need to do some more research into notifications and timers.

Comment: There is an iOS notification which is sent when a significant change in time occurs, including at midnight. If your app has been paused in the background for several days i’m not sure if you still get the notification the next time it is brought to the foreground. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1623059-significanttimechangenotificatio

Comment: This question and answer states that the significant time notification is only sent when your app is in the foreground. So you would also need to update when the app comes to the foreground (perhaps checking if the day has actually changed since the last refresh to avoid repeated refreshes during a single day) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67037463/why-is-significanttimechangenotification-not-emitted-or-not-received

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`notifications`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/notificationcenter/3813137-notifications) asynchronous sequence, launching a `for`-`await`-`in` loop in the [`.task`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/task(priority:_:)) view modifier:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = ViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            … 
        }
        .task {
            await viewModel.monitorDateChanges()
        }
    }
}

@MainActor
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    …
    
    func monitorDateChanges() async {
        let notifications = NotificationCenter.default.notifications(named: .NSCalendarDayChanged)
        
        for await _ in notifications {
            …
        }
    }
}
```

[Note](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/task(priority:_:)) that with the `.task` view modifier, “SwiftUI will automatically cancel the task at some point after the view disappears…”. So this loop will automatically be canceled when the view is dismissed.

Answer (score 2):

You can observe day changes in the calendar like:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let publisher = NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: .NSCalendarDayChanged)

    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello World")
            .onReceive(publisher) { output in
                print(output) //  Perform your task here
            }
    }
}
```